# Nested cakephp apps where parent controls authentication

Tags: authentication, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to find the best way to create a Portal type site which is to be used on a development server. The idea is that a client can login at the portal site, which will then display a list of projects that are currently being worked on for them that they can click and be taken to that project without the need to login again.

Base criteria:

- The portal site must be the only way to login and access the projects (other clients projects are on the server and i would like to control access to them through the portal)
- The client must remain logged in so they can browse multiple projects they own without the need to re-authenticate.
- Preferably with as little alteration to project code to accommodate portal as possible.

Is this possible with cakephp and if so what should i be reading up on to achieve this?

Comment: I have the same problem ! Did you find a solution ?!

Comment: i did not, I've put the project on the back burner as I have a few clients currently. I was toying with the idea of creating a random hash that would be sent from the portal to the project via url that would either bypass login or auto login.